# Eloquent belongsToMany relation with the not standard column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem. I have a [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI63n.png) and I wanna make belongsToMany relation with the not standard column name. 
I have table order as relation table and order detail as details, but when I make relation

**User.php (Model)**

```
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\OrderDetail', 'orders','user_id','id');
    }
```

but i recieve error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_details.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `order_details`.*, `orders`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `orders`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `order_details` inner join `orders` on **`order_details`.`id`** = `orders`.`id` where `orders`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) and `order_details`.`deleted_at` is null)

Eloquent search in order_detail `id` column, but I have order_id.

Eloquent have an instrument for change this?

Via belongsToMany I wanna receive all data from order_detail. This is real to make like that?

Comment: shouldn't the `User` be having many (`hasMany`) `OrderDetails` instead of belonging to many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make id column in order detail column and issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentioned: [Laravel doc. many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\OrderDetail', 'orders','user_id','order_id');
```